# Telegram Await CallbackQueryHandler not being called

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to call an async function inside my CallbackQueryHandler, however after calling `main()` nothing happens, the program run fine, but if i trigger the callback function, it doesn't work

this is my code

```py
from telegram.ext import Updater, CallbackQueryHandler

async def button(update, context) -> None:
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    data = query.data
    print(data)
    if await post_data(data):
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.chat_instance, text='Done!')

async def main() -> None:
    updater = Updater(TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN)
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button, run_async=True))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

await main()
```

am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`python-telegram-bot` does (yet) not natively support the `asyncio` module, see also [here](https://t.me/pythontelegrambotchannel/94). The `run_async` features uses threading.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.